# Set calendar type on whole application

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I've an application that is working fine with Gregorian calendar type. All API info for date is in Gregorian calendar type. But if users have Buddhist calendar I have crashes in some places. For example:

```
func days(from date: Date) -> Int {
    let beginningOfDay = date.beginningOfDay ?? date
    return Int(timeIntervalSince1970 - beginningOfDay.timeIntervalSince1970) / Int(TimeInterval.day)
}
```

How can I ignore user settings for calendar and force date to be in Gregorian calendar in whole application? Is it possible?

I've just founded converters, but I don't want to convert, I just want to force Gregorian calendar on whole app.

Thanks

Comment: What is `Date.beginningOfDay`? That sounds like you have some extension added to `Date` that in applying the user's calendar. You'll need to fix the extension (or better: rethink whether you should have such an extension; it was intentional to not have such a method on Date for exactly the reason you're encountering).

Comment: As a side note, this code is incorrect and can be off by a day. The tool you want is `DateComponents`

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for ur response. About ur second note - I already had an idea to refactor it with DateComponents :) But the main question is how to force calendar type for a whole app? 2 be precise, is it possible?

Comment: No. It's not possible. The user controls the calendar, and `.current` means "the user's requested calendar." If you want something else like "myAppsCalendar" then you can add an extension on Calendar to return that and use that method, not `current`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you've added a lot of extensions on `Date` that don't belong there. `Date` is a point in time. In order to talk about "days" you should be calling `Calendar` and `DateComponents` methods. This function isn't quite correct anyway. It can be off by a day depending on DST changes. You can't assume that a day is 24 hours long; some are 25 hours, and some are 23 hours.

The code you wanted was:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: d1, to: d2).day!
```

Likely somewhere in your extensions you have `Calendar.current`. That means "the current user calendar." There's no way to tell the system "even when I explicitly ask for the current user calendar, please give me something else." Look for the code that uses `Calendar.current` and replace it with `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Uparrowed. Btw. If I use just Date() and print it. In which calendar it will be converted. User current? Or my MacOs current? It's weird question, I know

Comment: When you print a Date, you're getting the debug output. It's not promised to be anything in particular; it's just meant to be a helpful to the programmer. It always returns the same format, regardless of calendar (`uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '+0000`; honestly I don't know what "u"; I'm just reading the `descriptionWithLocale:` code in CoreFoundation). My experiments suggest it ignores the current calendar as well. (Though I don't actually see how that happens from the code…) The short answer is you can't rely on it anyway.

Comment: @hardikbar I haven't been able to demonstrate it doing that. When I change my system calendar, the output of `print(Date())` doesn't change. How are you testing this?

Comment: Yeah. I have the same :) So it has confused me.
So, sir, thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: can i set globally. my app is old and I have big project.. and I have used calendar so many places.. Is it possible to method swizzling or something else.